# android : Retrieve GPS destination

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

one question regarding use of GPS application on android devices.

Is there a way, from an android app I create, to get from an existing GPS application the chosen destination.

For instance :
I drive, I use Google Map to go to Paris.
I want my app to get the information "Paris".

I imagine I'm asking if google/waze opened anything from their apps to get this information.

Thanks for help,
Ivan

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can.

Geocoding is the process of converting addresses (like "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA") into geographic coordinates (like latitude 37.423021 and longitude -122.083739), which you can use to place markers or position the map.

Reverse geocoding is the process of converting geographic coordinates into a human-readable address.

The Google Geocoding API provides a direct way to access a these services via an HTTP request.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: This is not answering the question that was asked.